# Modal Dialog box - VM transient Bug - Control+D from Windows

Tags: windows, modal-dialog, tcl, virtual-machine, tk-toolkit

I have found one more issue with vm transient in Windows OS, when modal dialog box created then press  from Keyboard to minimize. Then both parent and child windows are unusable. Same code works fine in Linux. after minimize,  the modal dialog box can be maximized. Please let me know if you have any alternate approach to solve this problem.

```
toplevel .child
frame .child.frame
button .child.frame.button -text "child_exit" -command "destroy .child"
pack .child.frame.button .child.frame

toplevel .parent
frame .parent.frame
button .parent.frame.button -text "parent_exit" -command "destroy .parent"
pack .parent.frame.button .parent.frame
```

## child is transient window working on behalf of parent

```
wm transient .child .parent
```

## to use this below grab command child is in active state to the keyboard activities

```
grab .child
wm withdraw .
```